# Used mv instead of rename; files gone

Tags: rename, mv

While trying to batch rename a bunch of directories with
`rename 's/foo/barr/g' *`
I carelessly got mv in there instead of rename (`mv 's/foo/bar/g' *`), which seems to have cleared out the directory. But, `ls *` shows all the files that were in there originally.
What gives? Are they still ... somewhere? `ls` alone or `ls -a` shows nothing, but `ls *` shows the full directory listing as before. Is it just reading the pointers? Can I recover easily?

Comment: What does "echo *" output?

Comment: ```echo *``` just the couple of files that survived the regex (so, nothing really). If I move those files out of the directory, then ```ls *``` says  ```ls: cannot access '*': No such file or directory``` and ```echo *``` just prints * back to stdout, but with files in the directory ```ls *``` lists the old contents

Comment: Ach, you're brilliant. Yes, everything just got moved into the last directory. Which is why ls * showed them all there ... as contents of the last directory. Thanks

Comment: ... and that's why I asked about what `echo *` outputted, as apposed to `ls *`.

Comment: If there are a couple of files + the directory, `ls *` should show you the name of the dir before listing its contents. That way, you can tell the files within are not on the current level. However, if there's only one dir and nothing else, then `ls *` turns into `ls thatdir`, and with a single arg, it _doesn't_ print the dir name, just the contents. Anyway, unless you specifically want to see the content of all dirs within the current dir (up to one level only, not recursively), I wouldn't use `ls *` at all. Just `ls` would do to list all files in the current dir.

Answer (score 3):

In `mv 's/foo/bar/g' *`, the `*` is expanded by the shell to the names of all non-hidden files or directories in the current working directory sorted lexically.

So `mv` will we called with `mv`, `s/foo/bar/g`, `afile`, `bfile`, `cfile`...

There are different possible outcomes.

- if you're on a GNU-like system, since you also forgot the `--` to mark the end of options and GNU `mv` accepts options after non-option arguments by default, if there's a file called `-t..` among that list. `mv` will move the files to the parent directory.
- if `*` expands to only one file, that becomes `mv s/foo/bar/g that-file`. If `that-file` is of type directory, it would move the `s/foo/bar/g` file into that directory. If not it would rename it to that-file. As I don't expect `s/foo/bar/g` to exist (and if it did, it would be `that-file` which would also give you an error), you would have gotten an error ther.
- if `*` expands to more than one file, then unless the last one if of type *directory*, you'll get an error. If it is of type directory than all files are moved into that directory.

The fact that `ls *` shows you your file suggests you're in the latter case above. That is, all the files have been moved into one directory, `ls` would show `that-directory`, and `*` now expands to `that-directory` only since you moved all other files into it, and `ls *` becomes `ls that-directory` which asks `ls` to list the contents of the `that-directory` directory.

It is possible that you have lost some files in the process if some of the files in `that-directory` have been overwritten by the ones that were moved, like if there was both a `foo` and `that-directory/foo` before.

If not, you may be able to restore your files by moving them back from `that-drectory` to the current working directory.

If you have run that command less than 10 minutes ago for instance, with `zsh`, you could do:

```
mv that-directory/*(cm-10) .
```

To move the files with a ctime that is less than 10 minutes old back to the current working directory.